# Which is the Firefox tool corresponding to Chrome->Web Developer ->Styles?

Tags: css, selenium, firefox-addon, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

When using Selenium, I found the `Chrome -> Web Developer -Styles` window very useful in getting CSS names of web controls.

I could right click on a web control and would get the CSS name for that control. This helped me avoid using XPath.

However, the in-house web application has blocked right click, so I am not able to use that facility any more. However I can still use Firebug to show me the XPath of a control since it works if I click the arrow in Firebug toolbar, which then displays XPath of every control that I hover.

So, the question is - Does Firefox addons have a corresponding CSS identifier tool?

Or

Is there a way around the right click block in Chrome? (For some reason Chrome used to guess or build the CSS name quite accurately which I did not find in Firefox.)

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but in Firefox you can avoid some right-click blocks by using shift+right click.

Answer (score 3):

The [*HTML* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel) of Firebug has a [*Styles* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel), where you can get all the applied styles for the selected element.

Comment: Thanks but i noticed that Chrome 'compiles' a CSS Selector which the Firefox Style panel does not. If there is something like 'Outpatient icon', Chrome will display it as 'Outpatient.icon' which turns out to be useful as Selenium identifier.